# Pydantic - How to add a field that keeps changing its name?

Tags: python, pydantic

I am working with an API that is returning a response that contains fields like this:

```
{
    "0e933a3c-0daa-4a33-92b5-89d38180a142": someValue
}
```

Where the field name is a UUID that changes depending on the request (but is not included in the actual request parameters). How do I declare that in a dataclass in Python? It would essentially be `str: str`, but that would interpret the key as literally "str" instead of a type.

Comment: what does a sample JSON response look like? is it just a single element key in there, where the key is a random value?

Comment: No, this is just a sub-element of a bigger JSON (that has multiple lists and dictionaries within it) that contains effectively random values as the key value. I didn't include those because they're fairly standard with static keys.

Comment: are the number of fields fixed? or I guess a better way of wording it would be, is there anything about the JSON object which contains the dynamic key names that is technically fixed, such as the type of the value, number of keys, length of characters in the key, etc.

Comment: also, do you need to retain the uuid values (keys)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally feel the simplest approach would be to create a custom *Container* dataclass. This would then split the dictionary data up, by first the *keys* and then individually by the *values*.

The one benefit of this is that you could then access the list by index value instead of searching by the random uuid itself, which from what I understand is something you won't be doing at all. So for example, you could access the first string value like `values[0]` if you wanted to.

Here is a sample implementation of this:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(init=False, slots=True)
class MyContainer:

    ids: list[str]
    # can be annotated as `str: str` or however you desire
    values: list[str]

    def __init__(self, input_data: dict):
        self.ids = list(input_data)
        self.values = list(input_data.values())

    def orig_dict(self):
        return dict(zip(self.ids, self.values))


input_dict = {
    "0e933a3c-0daa-4a33-92b5-89d38180a142": "test",
    "25a82f15-abe9-49e2-b039-1fb608c729e0": "hello",
    "f9b7e20d-3d11-4620-9780-4f500fee9d65": "world !!",
}

c = MyContainer(input_dict)
print(c)

assert c.values[0] == 'test'
assert c.values[1] == 'hello'
assert c.values[2] == 'world !!'

assert c.orig_dict() == input_dict
```

Output:

```
MyClass(values=['test', 'hello', 'world !!'], ids=['0e933a3c-0daa-4a33-92b5-89d38180a142', '25a82f15-abe9-49e2-b039-1fb608c729e0', 'f9b7e20d-3d11-4620-9780-4f500fee9d65'])
```